# Using the sed command in Unix

Tags: text-processing, sed

how do you take one word from a file and change it to an absolute path? Basically I need to take one word from a unix file and change it to a absolute directory path in that file. The file name is httpd.conf. The path for that file is /home/Tina/apache/conf/httpd.conf. The line is ServerRoot "/usr". The "/usr" is what i need to change to /home/Tina/apache.

```
Tina@Irv-PC ~/apache/conf
$ cat httpd.conf
#
# This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file. It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.

# Do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
ServerRoot "/usr"

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your documents.
#
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a before and after example: as it is, it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: ok the before line of the file is not a comment line and it says ServerRoot "/usr and i need to change the /usr to an absolute directory path

Comment: Tina, If you want helpful answers, please do as @jasonwryan suggests: _edit your question_ (because, unlike a comment, the question text can be formatted accurately) to include a short _before and after_  example (examples are critical because word descriptions often lack key details).

Comment: Yes, please do as the others have suggested. For one thing, that will help us understand your terms since both `/usr` and  `/home/Tina/apache/conf/httpd.conf` are absolute paths.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$ sed -i.orig '/ServerRoot/s_"/usr"_/home/Tina/apache_' /home/Tina/apache/conf/httpd.conf
```

If you want to put double quotes around `/home/Tina/apache`:

```
$ sed -i.orig '/ServerRoot/s_"/usr"_"/home/Tina/apache"_' /home/Tina/apache/conf/httpd.conf
```

Here at first we matched if the line contains "ServerRoot" (`/ServerRoot/`), if yes then we have made the required substitution (`s_"/usr"_"/home/Tina/apache"_`). As you have `/` in the path, we have used `_` as the `sed` substitution delimiters. The modified file will be `/home/Tina/apache/conf/httpd.conf` and the original file will be kept as `/home/Tina/apache/conf/httpd.conf.orig`.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid side effects, I'd replace the whole line:

```
sed -i.bak -e 's#^ *ServerRoot  *"/usr" *$#ServerRoot "/home/Tina/apache"#' httpd.conf
```

It is customary to use 's/from/to/', but since you have slashes everywhere, it's wise to use another character so you don't have to write `\/` for every path seperator slash in your expression. I put `^...$` around your from-expression to make sure to match only lines consisting of exactly that (`^` is beginning of line, `$` end of line)

The `-i` switch will edit your file in place, but make a backup to `httpd.conf.bak`, which is a very good idea when editing system config files.

In case your `sed` doesn't support alternate delimiters, you could try

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/^ *ServerRoot  *"\/usr" *$/ServerRoot "\/home\/Tina\/apache"/' httpd.conf
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your prompt reply. I am not getting an error, but it is not making the change either.

Comment: Hm. Any spaces in the line you want to replace? As originally written, `ServerRoot` must not be indented, nor may there be more than exactly one space between `ServerRoot` and `"..."`, nor may there be space or comments after the path. I'll update my answer to allow more spaces in a second.

Comment: so sorry but it still does the same, no error but no change in the file syntax either

Comment: no extra spaces

Comment: I can't help but think that I am over thinking this. Basically, it should be a simply replacement of "/usr" with "/home/Tina/apache".

Comment: Hm, if I run `sed -e 's#^ *ServerRoot  *"/usr" *$#ServerRoot "/home/Tina/apache"#' ` and paste in your lines, I can see it working. Have you checked that you can, in principle, manually edit `httpd.conf`?

Comment: when i run that script i get an empty prompt. When you are refering to me editting the file do you mean with vi editor?

Comment: @Tina: Yes, just to make sure there's no SELinux or similar security mechanism. (Or or you on Solaris by any chance? Not using `/` for sed might be a gnu extension not present in your version of sed then.)

Comment: No SELinux or Solaris. I am basically using Cygwin at this time.